# Find out if a JVM is using a particular jar file

Tags: java

How can you find out if a JVM or a product with a JVM is using a particular jar file?

Is the only why of doing this is to do a "lsof | grep name" ? or looking at the CLASSPATH how can you tell?

lsof | grep name and looking at the CLASSPATH

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-list-all-classes-loaded

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.